When is it safe to use `&'static var` in function input?
I have a function that requires my input to outlive the caller. Something like:
// Const /mod/constant.rs
pub const CONST_A: &str = "Constant Value";
// Caller
fn functionA() {
  let non_static_var = "hello world";
  do_something(non_static_var); // bad?
  do_something(CONST_A); // good?
}
// callee
fn do_something(input: &'static str) {
  //use the input that requires it to be `static
}

Is this the correct understanding where:

if I use a variable into the do_something(input) it would make the non_static_var into a static where it wouldn't be cleaned up?
If I use a const into the do_something(input) it is okay because const is already static lifetime?


non_static_var has type &'static str no matter what functions you pass it to.
